# Вызов функции при выборе нового option в select

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть `<select>` с созданными с помощью vue `<option>`. Как вызывать функцию при выборе нового `<option>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рад помочь

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  methods: {
    myFunction: function () {
      console.log("Aloha");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
  <select @change="myFunction()">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```